# Vue.js - adding html tags inside of string in array

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I have an array of strings in following form:

```
arr: [
"feature1 str1",
"feature2 str2",
"feature3 str3"
]
```

My goal is to highlight part of those strings with `<b>` tag (for example - "feature1 **str1**"). Further, strings must be rendered inside of vue template, for example:

```
<ul v-for="(feature, index) in arr" v-bind:key="index">
        <li>{{feature}}</li>
    </ul>
```

I'm not getting the result I want, so - the 'bold text' is not rendered.

If there's any solution or advice for fixing this problem - thanks in advance.

Comment: you're not getting what you want ... because there's no bold tag in your code - what's the criteria for which part of the string is bold? is it ... the last word? everything but the second word? anything that starts with `str`, anything that isn't the word `feature` ... there's many possibilities

Answer (score 0):

How about this?

```html
<ul v-for="(feature, index) in arr" v-bind:key="index">
  <li>{{feature.split(" ")[0]}} <b>{{feature.split(" ")[1]}}</b></li>
</ul>
```

this will only works if tthe arr value is always 2 word separateed by space and you want to highlight the 2nd word.

Comment: Thx, it is useful for me. And, how could I use regex and .match() to find a wanted word which needs to be highlighted?